# How many replications to eliminate Noise

Tags: sampling

Marbles marked 1-100 in a bag. You continuously draw 1 marble and then put it back. You only care about marbles 1-10 and want to keep track of how many times you pick those.

I'm interested in seeing what the probable skewness of the picks relating to marbles 1-10...so say after 300 draws 1-10 marbles are picked 1,2,3,3,2,3,4,3,2,1 number of times etc...

I'd appreciate some generic form based on the number of picks up to the point where the instances for the marbles should be the same at 90% confidence...

The

This is just an example -- I would appreciate a generic form where the number of marbles and the marbles you are interested in can be different.

Comment: If each draw is independent, then whether you draw a 1-10 or an 11-100 does not impact the next draw.  The skew is going to be the skew of a uniform distribution over that range.  You could simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I upvoted @EngrStudent's comment, it turns out this is not a 
simple problem, and I couldn't find an exact answer. The closest I came was:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347220

"Algorithm AS 145: Exact Distribution of the Largest Multinomial 
Frequency", which provides an algorithm to compute the formula given 
in the book "Combinatorial Chance": 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/9780852640579

For an approximation and some discussion of this distribution:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104948
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146418

Of course, this just gives you the maximum frequency. To answer your 
question, you also need the minimum frequency, and compute which one 
is further from the mean.

What you have here is a multinomial distribution. As @EngrStudent 
notes, adding the marbles 11-100 has no effect on the problem, so 
let's consider selecting $n$ marbles (with replacement) from a bag 
with $10 m$ marbles, with $m$ marbles labeled 1, $m$ marbles labeled 
2, etc. This is also equivalent to rolling a fair 10-sided die $n$ 
times.

As $n$ grows large, we would expect $\frac{n}{10}$ marbles with each 
number. However, some marbles will be chosen less frequently and some 
marbles will be chosen more frequently.

One sample version of the question: for a given $k$, how large must 
$n$ be to guarantee there's a 90% chance that each marble occurs 
$\frac{n}{10}\pm k$ times.

Of course, we can replace 90% with a different probability, and talk 
about $k$ as a percentage instead of an absolute number.

In general, we're asking: how far away from $\frac{n}{10}$ is the 
frequency of the most or least frequently appearing marble (whichever 
is further from $\frac{n}{10}$).

I ran a Monte Carlo simulation for 1000 draws (10,000 times), 
and found the following:

- The distribution of the frequency of the least picked marble:

[image: [[image25.gif]]]

- And the most picked marble:

[image: [[image26.gif]]]

- The frequency furthest away from the mean minus the mean:

[image: [[image27.gif]]]

- Since you're looking for a 90% confidence level, let's take the 
  cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the above:

[image: [[image28.gif]]]

So, if you pick 1000 marbles, you can be 90% confident that the 10 
resulting frequencies will be within 24 (or 24%) of the mean value of 
100. Of course, this is based on a Monte Carlo simulation, and 
shouldn't be regarded as absolutely precise.

For 2000 draws, jumping straight to the CDF:

[image: [[image29.gif]]]

So you can be 90% sure that all 10 marbles have a frequency 200 of $\pm$ 34 (ie, within 17% of the mean).

Finally, for 5000 draws:

[image: [[image30.gif]]]

You can be 90% sure that every marble's frequency will be between 446 
and 554, or 10.8% of the mean.

The general case here isn't easy. To a very rough approximation, the 
maximum distance from the expected (mean) frequency is normally 
distributed with $\mu =0.557 \sqrt{n}$ and $\sigma = 0.158 
\sqrt{n}$. Again this is based on Monte Carlo simulations and should 
not be considered exact.

I'm still working on the case where there are more or fewer than 10 marbles:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-multinomial.m